# cannot change the Configuration Database Server after SP SR1 upgrade?

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

Help!!

I have just run SharePoint SP1 on our dev environment and I am trying to run the SharePoint configuration tool so that I can finish the installation off bit I cannot change the Configuration Database server to a different server? I have looked in the webconfig file but there is no connection string to the SQL server that hosts all the dev databases? Where can I change this? I cannot get onto advance settings(it’s grayed out) the central admin now will not respond?

Can anybody point me in the right direction?

Many thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you run the configuration wizard after applying a patch (CU, SP etc) you do not need (should not) to specify the configuration database server. That is a local setting on the server (in the registry - but DO NOT fiddle with it) and you should just continue the psconfig wizard to finalize the installation/upgrade.

Comment: Glad to see you back here Wictor :)

Comment: many thanks Wictor, I have High availability set up and I need to make sure that I have taken all the servers out of the HA groups first and make sure all databases are sync'd, the only error message i get when i run the  spconfig is that the sql server cannot be contacted, many thanks again